# How to add ANY language in app description on AppStore? Tremendous impact on downloads!

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store

By submitting my application when I want to create application description in my national language (SLOVAKIAN) there's no choice to do so on Localization tab. There's only main languages: French, German, Spanish and so on...

But I know there are applications on Appstore with Slovakian language description (of course on Slovak AppStore). How they do this?

My application has localizations builded inside as described in Apple documentation (lproj folders). Everything properly tested, my app really change its labels texts when lang changed on iPhone. That's fine.

But how to write Slovakian application description in localization tab by submitting? 
EXAMPLE:
Look at this application in US store and Slovak store:[store item](http://bit.ly/aKXSk8) How they do this?

There must be some way. When you prepare multiple lang versions and use it's natural language in each store it would have tremendous impact on downloads, isn't?

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem with various apps in Catalan. Since Catalan is not available as an app description language we submit the Catalan description as Spanish, which is the language used in the App Store in Catalunya. All the apps were approved.

I suggest finding out the default language used by the Slovak App Store for descriptions and then submit your description in Slovakian using that language.

Comment: You mean to select only Slovak AppStore for distribution? I found application http://bit.ly/aKXSk8 which has Slovak description when I looked at Slovak store and English when looked at US store. Evidently this app is distributed globally.

Comment: No. I mean to use the "most similar" language to put the Slovakian description. The "most similar" language is the one picked by default in the Slovakian app store.

Comment: Default language in Slovak store is English. So, it would be contraproductive to replace English description with Slovak on worldwide distributed application. There must be some way. When you prepare multiple lang versions and use it's natural language in each store it would have tremendous impact on downloads, isn't?

Comment: Yes, you definitely want an English description if you plan to distribute the app globally. I don't know how "Počúvaj!" solved this problem if English is the default language for the Slovak App Store and there's no Slovakian option. However, their screenshots in the US App Store are in Slovakian. Did you try emailing Apple? They tend to reply to these kind of queries.

Comment: @Benny7500 The app you link to has used British English for the Slovak description - see http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sloochaj!/id350353249?mt=8